# Why does Batman say these words when King Kong attacks the building?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In *The Lego Batman Movie*, Batman & his team are hiding in some building and suddenly King Kong attacks the same building by jumping on it so building starts to fall down, then Batman says these words:

> This building's not up to **code!**

what exactly is Batman saying by this line?

I would say: his performance is not up-to the mark etc. what does code means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batman is referring to **[building codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_code)**. These are laws set by local authorities for the standards to which a building must be held. How many windows does a room need to be legally considered a "bedroom"? How big of an earthquake must the building be designed to withstand? Questions like that are answered in building codes.

Batman has determined that the building in question does not conform to the building codes it's governed by, or for short, it's "not up to code".

(Since it's the LEGO Batman Movie, I assume this is a joke of some kind: perhaps the LEGO city codes require buildings to be King Kong-proof?)